# doing a subset by a variable's values

Tags: r

I am using cars and this has two variables: speed and dist. 
I am trying to create groups based on speed - so all observations with speed==4 becomes an object, all observations with speed==7 is an object, all observations with speed==10 is an object and so on.

I've tried:

```
> apply(subset(cars,cars$speed))
Error in match.fun(FUN) : argument "FUN" is missing, with no default
> apply(subset(by=cars$speed))
Error in match.fun(FUN) : argument "FUN" is missing, with no default
> sapply(subset(by=cars$speed))
Error in match.fun(FUN) : argument "FUN" is missing, with no default
> sapply(subset(cars,cars$speed))
Error in match.fun(FUN) : argument "FUN" is missing, with no default
```

and they all don't work. Please help!

Comment: What is the desired result?  You may just want `split(cars, cars$speed)`

Comment: I'm trying to create different objects depending on car$speed so that I can create a frequency plot for each object. So I will have an object that only contains cars$speed ==4, and I will make a frequency plot of cars$dist just for cars$speed==4. So I will make a number of different plots and the data will be divided by cars$speed - does that even make sense?!?

Comment: do you want `cars[cars$speed == 4,]`, or `subset(cars,cars$speed == 4)`?  see `?subset` or `?\`[\`` for details

Comment: Have a look at `facet_wrap` or `facet_grid` from the `ggplot` package.

Comment: Furthermore: Read the info about how to give a [minimal reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example/5963610).

Comment: Also, you should look at `?apply` because the error you're getting specifically tells you why your current approach isn't working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A correct syntax for your apply function would be:

```
lapply(unique(cars$speed), function(xx) subset(cars, speed==xx))
```

Where you have a dataset followed by the **function** you want to apply. This is why you keep getting the error telling you that FUN is missing.

@RichardScriven 's `split(cars, cars$speed)` is a much more elegant solution however.

If you want to plot the frequency of dist for each speed you could do something like this:

```
library(ggplot2)
ggplot(cars, aes(dist)) +
  geom_bar() +
  facet_wrap(~speed)
```